# global services in Ember

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember 2 web app I have a couple of services (*notify* for UX feedback messaging and *intl* for translations) that are used everywhere. I wonder whether there is any drawbacks in injecting them in any controller (and even every route) through an initializer this way:

**/app/initializers/notify-intl.js**

```
export default {
  name: 'notify-intl',
  initialize: function (container, application) {
    application.inject('controller', 'intl', 'service:intl');
    application.inject('controller', 'notify', 'service:notify');
  }
};
```